# Keep same file owner for newly created files

Tags: linux, permissions, files, users, chown

This question is regarding samba file access.

I have created a folder A, and under folder A created two folders B and C. And also created three users A, B and C.

User A has access to all three folders but User B has only access to folder B and User C has only access to folder C.

Permission of B & C folders are:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 a b 4096 May 10 16:22 b
drwxrwxr-x 3 a c 4096 May 10 16:43 c
```

Problem:

When user B creates any new file under folder B, it's permission becomes

```
drwxr-x--- 2 b b 4096 May 10 16:21 New Folder
```

whereas I want it to keep the owner, group and permission same as folder B for any newly created files.

Comment: So you want `a` to own the file that `b` created?

Comment: "User A has access to all three folders" shall mean "write access"? Why do you want to change the owner, or is this about access rights only?

Comment: a has write access to all three folders but b has only access to folder b. but when user A creates any file under folder B, user b not getting access to that folder or file

Comment: ohh i am sorry i missed a main part. folder B and folder C is created under folder A.

Comment: @Kevin main question was wrong...I have edited it now.

Comment: and I also think SGID and SUID will do the job... but haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Folder b and c are owned by user b and c.
A file created by a user will belong to that user.

You can use the user permission for b and c, and the *group* permissions for a.
If you set the SGID bit (g+s) on a folder, created files will get the group permission of that folder.

```
mkdir a
chown a:a a
chmod g+s a

mkdir b
chown b:a b

mkdir c
chown c:a c
```

(assuming all users are in a group of the same name.)

Comment: so i don't need to do sticky bit in folder b and c?

Comment: they should get the bit automatically when being created inside a folder with that bit.

Comment: @user1723636, just so you understand the SGID bit and the "sticky bit" are 2 completely different things. See `man chmod`.

Comment: Also note that this solution is somewhat fragile, if users are able to move files into these directories, the SGID bit ownership will not get applied, so over time "strange" access problems will show up with specific files.

Comment: @slm - What should we do in order to make it less fragile?

Comment: @aust - Is make use of ACL's instead.